# I receive an error using an integer as a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

/*
I'm passing an integer as a parameter in a SQL stored procedure but receiving an error despite declaring the input value.

The intention is to use the value passed to the parameter in dynamic SQL in a WHILE LOOP.

This method works fine when passing string values through the parameter to the dynamic SQL but with integer values, an error is returned saying:

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 16
Must declare the scalar variable "@BUILDING_ID"

Below is the actual code I'm using:

### */

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.USP_History_Building

     @BUILDING int

AS 

DECLARE @quarterStart int = 2
DECLARE @quarterEnd int = 1
DECLARE @yearStart int = 17
DECLARE @yearEnd int = 19

DECLARE @BUILDING_ID int

DECLARE @year int
DECLARE @quarter int

DECLARE @quarterForDbName nvarchar(4)
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(max)

SET @year = @yearStart
SET @quarter = @quarterStart
SET @sqlStatement = ''

SET  @BUILDING_ID = @BUILDING

WHILE @year <= @yearEnd
BEGIN
   WHILE ((@year < @yearEnd AND @quarter <= 4) OR (@year = @yearEnd AND @quarter <= @quarterEnd))
   BEGIN
    SET @quarterForDbName = 'Q' + CAST(@quarter AS nvarchar(1)) + CAST(@year AS nvarchar(2))
--  

        SET @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement + '


        SELECT '''+@quarterForDbName+''' AS Quarter, ADDRESS_POINT_ID, BUILDING_ID, ADDR_LINE_1, ADDR_LINE_2, ADDR_LINE_3, ADDR_LINE_4, ADDR_LINE_5, ADDR_LINE_6 FROM EDB_'+ @quarterForDbName +'.dbo.POSTAL_ADDRESS PA WHERE PA.BUILDING_ID = @BUILDING_ID'

      SET @quarter = @quarter + 1

   END
   SET @quarter = 1
   SET @year = @year + 1

END

PRINT @sqlStatement
EXEC (@sqlStatement)
```

/*The expected result is about 8 rows showing 6 address fields for the previous 8 quarters.*/

Comment: where tyou got that error? Can you show us the result for the `PRINT @sqlStatement`

Comment: @Cinneach . . . This looks like SQL Server code, so I added the tag.  You should tag your questions with the database you are actually using. . . . I would also recommend that you ask *another* question.  Explain what you want to do with sample data and desired results.  A `WHILE` loop is not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
'WHERE PA.BUILDING_ID =' + @BUILDING_ID
```

**@BUILDING_ID** because it is a variable should be the other side of the quote.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
'WHERE PA.BUILDING_ID = @BUILDING_ID'
```

You need

```
'WHERE PA.BUILDING_ID =' + @BUILDING_ID
```

You can also use a parameter like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
EXECUTE ('SELECT ProductID, Name   
    FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.Product  
    WHERE ProductID = ? ', 952) AT SeattleSales;  
GO
```